# Server tag is not wellformed. Totally stuck

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-4.0

This server tag is not working. It constantly gives `server tag is not well formed`. I tried all combinations of tag using " and '. Nothing seems to work.

```
<asp:LinkButton CssClass="docs" OnClientClick='return selectionChanged('<%#Eval("Item1") %>')' runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Item2") %>' />
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you're in a databound control...is there any way you could do this in the row_databound event instead? (Sometimes working with nested single and double quotes gets hokey and it's just easier to do it in the codebehind file)

Answer (score 3):

If Item1 is a number, you could try this::

```
<asp:LinkButton CssClass="docs" OnClientClick='<%# string.Concat("return selectionChanged(",Eval("Item1"),".toString())") %>' runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Item2") %>' />
```

Or use a custom method:

```
<asp:LinkButton CssClass="docs" OnClientClick='<%# GetOnClick(Eval("Item1")) %>' runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Item2") %>' />

protected string GetOnClick(object item1)
{
    return string.Format("return selectionChanged('{0}')", item1);
}
```

Comment: The first one still blows up because of the quotes - the second one seems to work ok.

Comment: Is Item1 a number or alphanumeric?

Answer (score 1):

Hey how about this :

```
<asp:LinkButton CssClass="docs" 
OnClientClick='<%#Eval("Item1", "return selectionChanged(\"{0}\")") %>' 
runat="server" 
Text='<%#Eval("Item2") %>' />
```

Answer (score -1):

you've used single quotes in OnClientClieck declaration
try this:

```
<asp:LinkButton 
    CssClass="docs" 
    OnClientClick="return selectionChanged('<%#Eval("Item1") %>')" 
    runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Item2") %>' />
```

or assign OnClientClick value on server side (for example in Row/ItemDataBound event handler)

Comment: That one still blows up because of the mixed quotes.